# How can I create a dictionary from two lists, one list is the keys, the other contains nested values?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested-lists

I have two lists:

```
list_values = [['James', '40', 'Engineer'], ['Mary', '30', 'Nurse]]
```

and

`keys = ['Name', 'Age' 'Profession']`.

My intention is to create a dictionary with the following output:

```
{'name': 'James', 'Age': '40', 'Profession': 'Engineer'},{'name': 'Mary', 'Age': '30', 'Profession': 'Nurse'}
```

However, my code only gives me contents from the first dictionary generated, that is:

```
{'name': 'James', 'Age': '40', 'Profession': 'Engineer'}
```

Here is the code:

```
dict_content = {}
for person in list_values:
    for val in range(len(keys)):
        key = keys[val]
        value = person[val]
        dict_content[key] = value
print(dict_content)
```

For instance, I do not know why my code only runs the inner `for loop` and does not come back to pick the second nested list in the first `for loop`. Am interested in knowing why my code is wrong for I have spend almost a day trying to figure the problem to no success.

Comment: Your desired output is a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary.

Comment: You're overwriting the same dictionary every time through the loop, not creating a different dictionary for each person.

Comment: Thank you for your two comments.

Answer (score 7):

Just a one-liner does it:

```
dct = [dict(zip(keys,vals)) for vals in list_values]
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'James', 'Age': '40', 'Profession': 'Engineer'}, {'Name': 'Mary', 'Age': '30', 'Profession': 'Nurse'}]
```

Comment: Powerful man. Be blessed. Thank you.

Comment: Just noticed that it is still a list with two dictionaries inside it.

Comment: Right.  That's exactly what you showed.  You didn't show the outer brackets, but your example shows TWO dictionaries.  There's no other way to do it.  There can only be one `"Name"` key in a dictionary.

Comment: You are right Tim. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_values = [['James', '40', 'Engineer'], ['Mary', '30', 'Nurse']] 
keys = ['Name', 'Age', 'Profession']
dict = {k:[] for k in keys}
for person in list_values:
    for i in range(len(keys)):
        dict[keys[i]].append(person[i])
```

In this case a dataframe can be easily generated with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)`.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but that's not the output he was seeking.

Comment: Yes, I realized it. Just want to show how to do it in case a real dict is needed

Answer (score 1):

In python, dictionary keys must be unique, meaning you can't really have multiple names and ages inside one dictionary. Instead, you can make a list of these dictionaries. You can also combine two lists into a dict using the `zip` function, which returns a new list containing tuples of the corresponding indexes. So `zip([1, 2], [3, 4])` would return `[(1, 3), (2, 4)]`. You can then construct a dictionary from that using `dict(zipped_list)`
With all that in mind, the code to do what you want is this

```py
list_values = [['James', '40', 'Engineer'], ['Mary', '30', 'Nurse']] 
keys = ['Name', 'Age', 'Profession']
dict_list = [dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in list_values]
```